# "Old" asp:CustomValidator errors show up after clicking the Back button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form that uses a CustomValidator to check the contents of a textbox.  If the textbox's contents are invalid when a "Submit" button is pressed, the error message is displayed properly and the "Submit" operation doesn't happen.  When the textbox's contents are corrected and the submit button is pushed, the error disappears and the next page is presented properly.  So far so good.

But, if the user then clicks the Back button in browser, the original page is displayed with the error message, even though the textbox still shows the corrected text.  Can anyone offer suggestions about what I may be doing wrong?

Code front:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" ValidationGroup="Register" />

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valUsername" OnServerValidate="Validate_Username" ValidationGroup="Register" Display="Dynamic" />

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnNext" OnClick="btnNext_OnClick" ValidationGroup="Register" CausesValidation="True" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        valUsername.ErrorMessage = Resources.Resource.RegisterPageValidateUsername;
    }
}

protected void btnNext_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("Register");

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       //Do stuff
    }
}

protected void Validate_Username(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    var user = GetUser(txtUsername.Text);
    args.IsValid = user == null;
}
```

Comment: when you click the back button, do you get the warning from the browser regarding resubmitting the form?
try wrapping your validation logic in a if(!Page.IsPostback) check, same as you are doing in Page_Load

Comment: put a breakpoint on all 3 methods then when you click the back button find out what's firing, then think about how you want to handle it

Comment: No, I don't get warning from the browser regarding resubmitting the form.